# Componente Auth do Cakephp não funciona corretamente

Tags: php, cakephp, autenticação

Estou fazendo uma tela de cadastro de usuários. Quando o usuário completa o cadastro, é redirecionado a uma área restrita. Nessa mesma tela, existe um campo login e senha para os eles se logarem. Porém, a única coisa que funciona é o cadastro, mas mesmo assim, não está redirecionando para a área restrita. Meus códigos estão assim:

AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array('Auth');

function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->fields = array(
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password'
    );

    $this->Auth->loginAction = array(
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'login'
    );
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array(
        'controller' => 'profiles',
        'action' => 'index'
    );
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = '/';

    $this->Auth->authError = 'Area Restrita! Efetue login!'; // Mensagem ao entrar em area restrita
    $this->Auth->loginError = 'Nome de usuario ou senha não conferem!'; // Mensagem quando não se autenticar
    $this->Auth->allow('pages', 'display');

}

}
```

UsersController:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

public function register() {
    $this->loadModel('User');
    //$this->autoRender = FALSE;
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $day = $this->request->data['day'];
        $mouth = $this->request->data['mouth'];
        $year = $this->request->data['year'];
        $birth = $year . "-" . $mouth . "-" . $day;
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        if ($this->User->save(array(
                    'name' => $this->request->data['name'],
                    'username' => $this->request->data['email1'],
                    'password' => $this->request->data['pass'],
                    'birthday' => $birth,
                    'sex' => $this->request->data['sex'],
                    'date_sign' => $date
                ))) {
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect(array('controller' => 'profiles', 'action' => 'index'));              
        }
    }
}

public function login() {
    //$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());   
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Usuário ou senha inválido'));
    }
}

function logout() {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}

}
```

User (Model):

```
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class User extends AppModel {

public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

E no layout default.ctp, o form que faz o cadastro eu estou apontando para "users/register" e o form para o login, aponto para "users/login"

Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode estar errado?

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
if ($this->User->save(array(
                'name' => $this->request->data['name'],
                'username' => $this->request->data['email1'],
                'password' => $this->request->data['pass'],
                'birthday' => $birth,
                'sex' => $this->request->data['sex'],
                'date_sign' => $date
            ))) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('O usuários foi salvo.');
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'profiles', 'action' => 'index'));              
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Erro no cadastro.');
}
```

Para redirecionamentos do controller use sempre $this->redirect().

Função Login no UsersController:

```
public function login() {
//Verifica o tipo de requisição.
if ($this->request->is('post')) {  
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Usuário ou senha inválido'));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Outra coisa, ao invés de criar um novo array dentro do save, altere o próprio array do $this->request->data e use o if/save apenas assim: `if($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {...}`, o código fica mais limpo.

Comment: Então, continua não funcionando, nem redireciona para a área restrita e nem o login

Comment: Então não está salvando, você verificou se o novo usuário aparece no banco de dados?

Comment: Você tentou seguir o tutorial do blog, na página do Cake? Recomendo muito, antes de tentar criar uma aplicação sozinho.
E cuidado com as versões do book e da API, se não for a mesma do seu pacote do cake, pode dar confusão.

Comment: Sim, tentei o tutorial e o usuário está salvando, verifiquei no banco, também dei a permissão no $this->Auth->allow()

Comment: Então a versão que eu estou usando é a última, baixei direto do site

Comment: Tente adicionar os flashes e ver o que ele responde, editei a resposta.

Comment: Então, coloquei o seu flash e não deu mensagem nenhuma, mas me apareceu a mensagem Area Restrita! Efetue login! que eu tinha colocado no $this->Auth->authError

Comment: Verifique a resposta novamente, o que acredito estar ocorrendo é que você não está verificando o tipo de requisição, ao acessar o form, a requisição sempre vai ser 'get' e ao postar o usuário e senha, 'post', então após você inserir e dar submit, ele irá executar a função login, com os dados do form preenchido.
Esta percepção do que é get/post/put/delete é muito importante para poder orientar o método de que forma ele deve se comportar em cada requisição.

Comment: Puts não vai, eu to achando que tem alguma coisa errada com o AppController pq eu mudei o $this->Auth->loginAction colocando outro controller e outra action e não mudou a url, sempre volta p o users/login

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13398/discussion-between-marcelo-aymone-and-daniel-swater)